# Feature Geometry/shape changed event in arcObjects

Tags: shapefile, arcobjects, geometry, feature-class

I have a feature class(polyline). there are 5 features in the feature class. I want to get notification when user changed property any of feature of feature class. How it can be achieved ? I am using arcmap 10.0.
say, user got to arcmap edit mood. then make a straight line feature to curved feature. How can I get this notification that user changed its shape??

python and .net is my development technology.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using ArcObjects / .NET, you would have to listen to the OnChangeFeature event of the Editor object e.g.

```cs
var editorUid = new UIDClass { Value = "esriEditor.Editor" };
var editEvents = (IEditEvents_Event)Application.FindExtensionByCLSID(editorUid);
editEvents.OnChangeFeature += obj => { MessageBox.Show("Change " + obj.OID); };
```

Please consult the ArcObjects documentation for more information: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/000100000154000000.htm

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But I cann't find the "editor" object from your code[var editEvents = (IEditEvents_Event) editor;]

Comment: sorry for my above comments. It works great. I think, my problem will be solved :)

Comment: @Monir Yeah you're right. I changed the code so that it gets the Editor object from the Application, which is available if you have an extension, a command etc.

Comment: Can I get featureClass path of edited feature from somhow ?

Comment: @Monir Maybe you should ask that in a separate question. But the short answer is `var featureClass = obj.Class as IFeatureClass`

Answer (score 1):

If you cast the `obj` passed to `OnChangeFeature` as `IFeatureChanges`, you can check `ShapeChanged` to determine if the shape has changed (and not just an attribute).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I get featureClass path of edited feature from somhow ?